# In boost sink and source in one file device

Tags: c++, boost

The file_sink and file_source classes performs read and writes. But is there a class which can be used as both sink and source on files.

Comment: [The API reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) is pretty good...

Answer (score 1):

Sinks and sources are "special-case" devices that allow *just* writing or *just* reading, respectively.

However, plenty of other device modes exist.

**For this task, I believe you want [`basic_file`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html?path=4.2.2.8).**

Comment: The operating keyword here, that baffled me too, is _private inheritance_. The more specific classes _privately_ inherit from `basic_file`, exposing on part of the behaviour

Comment: @sehe: `file_sink` and `file_source` don't inherit from _anything_, as far as I can tell...

Comment: [`template<typename Ch> struct basic_file_source : private basic_file<Ch> { ... };`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/iostreams/device/file.hpp)

Comment: @sehe: Okay, the API reference doesn't show that in its synopsis. Suppose there's not much reason for it to.